# what is liquidation value in kyle (1985) model

Tags: liquidity

I am thoroughly reading my first academic literature and I have found myself overwhelmed by terms that have been generalised in my studies.

It is from "Continuous Auction and Insider Trading" by Albert S. Kyle 1985, states :

> The ex post liquidation value of the risky asset, denoted $\tilde\upsilon$ is normally distributed with mean $p_0$ and variance $\Sigma_0$.

What is liquidation value actually? And why it has normal distribution?

I apologise for my ignorance.

Regards,

Comment: Exactly what the name suggests: the price (or price+dividend) at which the asset is going to be sold next period.

Comment: This is a theoretical model of trading. We are assuming we are trading something today that will have some value tomorrow, but we don't know that value yet, so it is random. Furthermore there is no "day after tomorrow" in this model, everyone will "liquidate" their position tomorrow at this price. This is being assumed to keep things simple, i.e. it is a two period model.

Comment: The liquidation value has a normal distribution because this is tractable: the calculation of conditional expectations by market participants (sometimes called the filtering problem) is available in closed form which has intuitive properties.